# Show my comment on an answer without refresh, in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

When I post a comment to an answer I submit it but it shows the answer without my comment.

If I then refresh it shows correctly.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce on an LG Optimus L9. The comment appeared below the answer as soon as I submitted it.

Comment: Hmm. It's happened to me twice now. Both items it was the first comment on someone else's answer. I'm on a galaxy s2.

Comment: It's mocking me now. It did it for the comment above.

Comment: yes I have noticed this issue twice, not happening every time but some time.

Comment: This happens for me pretty consistently. On questions as well, and also after submitting an edit. Edit: Heh. it _would_ be this comment that works, huh. (Only some of the edits, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the creation of this bug, a lot of changes have been done to the comment interface on Android which seem to have fixed this issue.